# Is there any reference to the selected element in a delegated 'on' handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-delegation

When using jQuery `on`, is there a way to get the selected element from within the handler, as opposed to the event target? For example, none of the following is related to `body`:

```
$('body').on('click', 'h1', function(e){
    console.log(e.target);
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
    console.log(this);
});
```

Comment: Well, here is the correct answer: event.delegateTarget http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of `e.delegateTarget` in your event handler will be the element that actually handled the event which in your example will be the `<body>` tag.

As it looks like you already know, `e.target` will be set to the object that originated the event (might be a child object in your `<h1>`) and `e.currentTarget` and `this` will be set to the object that matches your `"h1"` selector.

Most of the time, it's the object that matches your `<h1>` selector that you want, but you can use `e.delegateTarget` if you want to know which object intercepted the event.

jQuery documentation reference: http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/

Comment: Not exactly. `e.target` might be set to any element *in the h1* that was actually clicked.